# When I use model in django, and I use many to one, How do I get the top 5 by comparing the count of the many

Tags: django, django-models

this is my models:

```
class question(models.Model):
    question_user_id = models.ForeignKey('log_in.user', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    question_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    question_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    question_content = models.CharField(max_length=10000)

class comment(models.Model):
    comment_question_id = models.ForeignKey(question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    comment_content = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    comment_user = models.ForeignKey('log_in.user',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

we can know that comment and question is in a relationship of many to one, I wonder how can i get the top 5 questions which has the most comments, I know I can find all the questions and use some arithmetics to solve it, but it costs a lot, can I just use the django model's Built-in methods to solve the problem?
maybe like use `question.objects.order_by(*),(actually, I don't know what to write in the *)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve it by this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Question.objects.filter(question_user_id=user_object).annotate(ccount=Count('comment').order_by('-ccount')[:5]
```

*FYI:* in model defination, please don't use `something_id` as field name, because underneath, django creates a table with name `something_id` if the table's name is `something`. And the class name should be Pascal Case according to [pep8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but 'Count('comment_question_id)' should be 'Count('comment')', for we use ForeignKey to add relationship between model 'comment' and model 'question', we should use the class name to search.

Comment: Yes, you are right. my mistake. Updating the answer

Comment: @Lanceli also prefixing the models fields names with the models names is counter-productive - useless typing when coding and just line-noise when reading.